# Outer join by group (recreate from last post due to wrong information)

Tags: sql, full-outer-join

A

| porow | sorow | poid | soid | poreference | posource | poprice | sopriceconfirm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 214446 | 215712 | AAA | PO | 50 | 1 |
| 1 |  | 215355 | 217902 | BBB | PO | -60 | 0 |

B

| porow | sorow | poid | soid | poreference | sosource | soprice | sopriceconfirm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 214446 | 215712 | AAA | SO | -190 | 0 |
|  | 1 | 215355 | 217902 | BBB | SO | 0 | 0 |

```
select 
    b.[porow], a.[sorow], b.poid, a.soid, 
    b.[poreference], b.[posource], a.[poprice], a.[sosource], 
    b.[soprice], a.[sopriceconfirm]
from 
    tableA a
full outer join 
    tableB b on a.[sorow] = b.[porow]
```

I want this result:

| porow | sorow | poid | soid | poreference | posource | poprice | sosource | soprice | sopriceconfirm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 214446 | 215712 | AAA | PO | 50 | SO | -190 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 215355 | 217902 | BBB | PO | -60 | SO | 0 | 0 |

However, I'm getting more rows.

When `poreference, porow, sorow` match in both tables I want to show `soprice` from `tableB` joined with table `tableA`.

If I remove poreference 'BBB' from one table then it works. But not both.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join on equal fields.

Something like this:

```sql
select 
    b.[porow], a.[sorow], b.poid, a.soid, 
    b.[poreference], b.[posource], a.[poprice], a.[sosource], 
    b.[soprice], a.[sopriceconfirm]
from tableA a
full outer join tableB b
 on     a.[poid] = b.[poid]
    and a.[soid] = b.[soid]
    and a.[poreference] = b.[poreference]
```